# Synthesis of Cyclohexenon from Anisole

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

(I'll write organic compounds as SMILES notation)

I am learning about carbonyl compounds these days, and I have a problem.
One way of cyclohex-2-ene-1-one synthesis is using anisole following the reaction.

\begin{aligned}
\mathtt{c1ccccc1OC>Li.NH_3}&\mathtt{>C1C=CCC=C1OC}\\
\mathtt{>H^+}&\mathtt{>C1C=CCC=C1O}\\
\mathtt{>H^+}&\mathtt{>C1C=CCCC1=O}&(\mathtt{cyclohexｰ3ｰeneｰ1ｰone})\\
\mathtt{>H^+}&\mathtt{>C1=CCCCC1=O}&(\mathtt{cyclohexｰ2ｰeneｰ1ｰone})
\end{aligned}

But I cannot understand the last reaction. What kind of reaction is taking place here, it would be helpful if you could indicate the reaction mechanism.

(This is the structure formula of the above reaction)
[image]

Comment: It's two tautomerisations, like penultimate reaction going backward and again forward.

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/164480/acid-hydrolysis-of-birch-reduced-anisole

Mechanism of this rearrangement is explained here